# How can i use is not empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can i do a condition with is not empty, or has a value?

I tried but is not working

```
     <% if params[:search_num_letter].values.any?  and params[:search_letter_log].values.any? %>
          No data
     <% else %>
         <% if params[:search_num_letter] == ""  and params[:search_letter_log] == "" %>
            No data
         <% else %> 
            my code
         <% end %>
     <% end %>
```

I will really appreciate help.

Comment: What type of objects are `params[:serach_num_letter]` and `params[:search_letter_log]`? In the first conditional you treat them as a hash, but then in the subsequent one you treat them as a string. `values` is a method for a hash.

Comment: You can try .blank? method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `params[:search_num_letter].values.any?` you probably want to drop the `.values` and just do `params[:search_num_letter].any?`.